Laravel reverb is not working in Digital Ocean App platfrom
In my local machine broadcasting and it works fine but in Production which is Digital ocean app platform it cannot connect to the server.
.env
BROADCAST_DRIVER=reverb

REVERB_APP_ID=my-app-id
REVERB_APP_KEY=my-app-key
REVERB_APP_SECRET=my-app-secret
REVERB_HOST=0.0.0.0        # Bind to all interfaces
REVERB_SCHEME=https         # Use https for security, especially since your app is hosted publicly
REVERB_PORT=6001            # Default port for WebSocket connections 

broadcasting.php
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Broadcaster
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default broadcaster that will be used by the
    | framework when an event needs to be broadcast. You may set this to
    | any of the connections defined in the "connections" array below.
    |
    | Supported: "pusher", "ably", "redis", "log", "null"
    |
    */

    'default' => env('BROADCAST_DRIVER', 'reverb'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Broadcast Connections
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may define all of the broadcast connections that will be used
    | to broadcast events to other systems or over websockets. Samples of
    | each available type of connection are provided inside this array.
    |
    */

    'connections' => [

        'reverb' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',  // Reverb mimics Pusher
            'key' => env('REVERB_APP_KEY', 'some-random-key'),
            'secret' => env('REVERB_APP_SECRET', 'some-random-secret'),
            'app_id' => env('REVERB_APP_ID', 'some-app-id'),
            'options' => [
                'host' => env('REVERB_HOST', 'mydigitaloceanlink'),  // Your actual domain
                'port' => env('REVERB_PORT', 443),  // Port for WSS
                'scheme' => env('REVERB_SCHEME', 'https'),  // Secure WebSocket
                'useTLS' => env('REVERB_SCHEME', 'https') === 'https',  // Match TLS to scheme
                'encrypted' => true,  // Ensure connection encryption
            ],
        ],

        'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
                'useTLS' => env('REVERB_SCHEME') === 'https',
            ],
        ],

        'ably' => [
            'driver' => 'ably',
            'key' => env('ABLY_KEY'),
        ],

        'redis' => [
            'driver' => 'redis',
            'connection' => 'default',
        ],

        'log' => [
            'driver' => 'log',
        ],

        'null' => [
            'driver' => 'null',
        ],

    ],

];


reverb.php
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Reverb Server
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default server used by Reverb to handle
    | incoming messages as well as broadcasting message to all your
    | connected clients. At this time only "reverb" is supported.
    |
    */

    'default' => env('REVERB_SERVER', 'reverb'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Reverb Servers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may define details for each of the supported Reverb servers.
    | Each server has its own configuration options that are defined in
    | the array below. You should ensure all the options are present.
    |
    */

    'servers' => [

        'reverb' => [
            'host' => env('REVERB_HOST', '0.0.0.0'),
            'port' => env('REVERB_PORT', 9000),
            'hostname' => env('REVERB_HOST'),
            'options' => [
                'tls' => [],
            ],
            'max_request_size' => env('REVERB_MAX_REQUEST_SIZE', 10_000),
            'scaling' => [
                'enabled' => env('REVERB_SCALING_ENABLED', false),
                'channel' => env('REVERB_SCALING_CHANNEL', 'reverb'),
                'server' => [
                    'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
                    'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
                    'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
                    'username' => env('REDIS_USERNAME'),
                    'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD'),
                    'database' => env('REDIS_DB', '0'),
                ],
            ],
            'pulse_ingest_interval' => env('REVERB_PULSE_INGEST_INTERVAL', 15),
            'telescope_ingest_interval' => env('REVERB_TELESCOPE_INGEST_INTERVAL', 15),
        ],

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Reverb Applications
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may define how Reverb applications are managed. If you choose
    | to use the "config" provider, you may define an array of apps which
    | your server will support, including their connection credentials.
    |
    */

    'apps' => [

        'provider' => 'config',

        'apps' => [
            [
                'key' => env('REVERB_APP_KEY'),
                'secret' => env('REVERB_APP_SECRET'),
                'app_id' => env('REVERB_APP_ID'),
                'options' => [
                    'host' => env('REVERB_HOST'),
                    'port' => env('REVERB_PORT', 443),
                    'scheme' => env('REVERB_SCHEME', 'https'),
                    'useTLS' => env('REVERB_SCHEME') === 'https',  // Enable TLS for HTTPS
                ],
                'allowed_origins' => ['*'],
                'ping_interval' => env('REVERB_APP_PING_INTERVAL', 60),
                'activity_timeout' => env('REVERB_APP_ACTIVITY_TIMEOUT', 30),
                'max_message_size' => env('REVERB_APP_MAX_MESSAGE_SIZE', 10_000),
            ],
        ],

    ],

];


in my controller i try to broadcast this
                       broadcast(new FileUploaded($user->id, $file->getClientOriginalName(), $counter, $asset->id));
                   } catch (\Exception $e) {
                       // Log detailed error information
                       Log::error('Error broadcasting FileUploaded event:', [
                           'message' => $e->getMessage(),
                           'file' => $e->getFile(),
                           'line' => $e->getLine(),
                           'trace' => $e->getTraceAsString(),
                       ]);
                   } 


i got following error:
Local. ERROR: Error broadcasting FileUploaded event: ("message": "Pusher error: CURL error 7: Failed to connect to 0.0.0.0 port 6001 after 6 ms: Connection refused (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for https://0.0.0.0/apps/my-app-id/events?auth_key=my-app-key&auth_timestamp=1727691940&auth_version=1.0&body_md5=bdfd3fdcc3c19ab647114c8d4ca230e2&auth_signature=cd729c19fa4d846b99f424b7a856584445272f695ffe9ff26cc786@fe0e39a71.", "file": "/workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Broadcasting/Broadcasters/PusherBroadcaster.php", "line": 164, "trace": "#0 /workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Broadcasting/BroadcastEvent.php(92): Illuminate\Broadcasting\Broadcasters\PusherBroadcaster->broadcast()")

Same thing happens with port 443 and port 8080 i got ssl error which is understandable. In console when i run start the server it is starting.
php artisan reverb:start --debug

   INFO  Starting server on 0.0.0.0:6001.  

  Pruning Stale Connections .......................................................................................  
  Pinging Inactive Connections 

From postman i tried wss connection but it is tied out. I am out of options now.
